# Creating a dictionary of words as keys mapped to their instances in a set of 'documents'

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I need to take a list of tuples that includes sentences that are preprocessed as such (the 0 is an integer that corresponds to the publication, and the set at the end finds all unique words in the sentence):

```
(0, 'political commentators on both sides of the political divide agreed that clinton tried to hammer home the democrats theme that trump is temperamentally unfit with the line about his tweets and nuclear weapons', {'weapons', 'political', 'theme', 'line', 'and', 'sides', 'commentators', 'of', 'tried', 'about', 'is', 'agreed', 'clinton', 'the', 'home', 'to', 'divide', 'tweets', 'that', 'democrats', 'unfit', 'on', 'temperamentally', 'both', 'hammer', 'his', 'nuclear', 'with', 'trump'})
```

and returns a dictionary that includes the words as the key, and a list of integers that are the "index" position of the word as the value. i.e if this sentence was the 12th of the list, the dictionary value would contain 12 next to all the present words.

I know that I need to enumerate the original set of documents and then take the words from the set in the tuple, but I'm having a hard time finding the proper syntax to iterate into the sets of words within the tuple. Right now I'm stumped as to even where to start. If you want to see my code for how I produced the tuples from an original document of lines here it is.

def makeDocuments(filename):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    
    g = [l for l in f]

    return [tuple([int(l[0:2]), re.sub(r'\W', ' ',(l[2:-1])), set(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z%]+', l))]) for l in g]
```

A test case was provided for me, upon searching for a given key the results should look something like:

assert index['happiness'] == [16495,66139,84943,
85998,91589,93472,
120070,133078,193349]

where the word 'happiness' occurs inside the sentences at those index positions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If these are python tuples in a file, instead of your complicated parsing, you could do `ast.literal_eval()` on each line and get the tuple you want. Then you could take that set in position 2 and use it to fill in a dictionary that maps the names in the set to a list of the indexes where it is found.

Comment: Is the purpose to create a hash index of the position in the file where the word resides

Answer (score 2):

Parsing that string is hard and you have pretty much just done a brute force extraction of data. Instead of trying to guess whether that's going to work on all possible input, you can use python's `ast` module to convert literals (what you type into a python program to represent stings, tuples, sets and so forth) into python objects for processing. After that, its just a question of associating the words in the newly created tuple to the indexes.

```
import ast

def makeDocuments(filename):
    catalog = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            index, text, words = ast.literal_eval(line)
            for word in words:
                if word not in catalog:
                    catalog[word] = []
                catalog[word].append(index)
    return catalog
```